# How to export a config map containing files as YAML such that the YAML contains file in pipe notation and not as an escaped string

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, configmap

kubectl get cm coredns -n kube-system -o yaml

There is a file in it called `Corefile` which appears as a escaped string with many `\n`
Instead I want it to be exported using the pipe notation of YAML.

How to do it?

Comment: They're both the same, and if you reapply the file you have in source control you could get either presentation format out.  I don't think you have that level of control over the YAML printer in `kubectl`.  Why does this matter to you; can you write your own program using the Kubernetes API if you do need a specific presentation?

Comment: Because I want to be able to easily insert/copy/edit/delete/ lines form it. It is not convenient when its all garbled into a single line. Also in GitOps, it helps if the changes are on spearate lines from a diff usability perspective. I wonder why it outputs it that way because there is another file in the same config map which is output using the pipe notation.

Comment: In a GitOps setup, I'd expect your tooling to work principally on what's checked into source control, not the `kubectl get` output?

Comment: Imagine, I pull things from the cluster modify them and track them in the repo. Anyway this is turning into, not having to do what the question asks. Getting a clean output is desirable for n number of reasons. This is just one of them.